# How to troubleshoot missing external libraries from Webpack UMD build? Chrome console shows defined variable while code breaks with undefined variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack, babeljs, umd

I am trying to create a reusable `d3` library, building the code with Babel 7 and then bundling a JS file with Webpack with UMD output. On Webpack config d3 is set as an external library:

```
externals: {
  d3: 'd3',
  ...
```

On a simple HTML file I load `d3`, `react` and `react-dom` with `<script>` tags and everything is loaded fine. I have no errors inside my library on the React wrapper, yet calling any function of `d3` says that it is `undefined`. With a breakpoint on that code line, running on Chrome console the code `d3.min(data)` returns `-46`, the same as calling it outside of my library, but when I run the line of code I get the error:

```
processDataset.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined
    at processDataset (processDataset.js:8)
    at VizService.setData (VizService.js:14)
    at new VizService (VizService.js:8)
    at new MiniVisual (MiniVisual.js:24)
    at color-coded-bar.html:26
```

I have tried to set `window.d3 = d3;`, loading different `d3` versions but nothing changes. How does the console of the Chrome devtools fail to give a correct output? What am I missing here? Maybe the problem is being obfuscated by the source mapping done by Chrome, how can I disable it and do proper debbuging?

The original `processDataset.js`:

```
import d3 from 'd3';

function processDataset(data, { scale = 'linear', range }) {
  const dataMin = d3.min(data);
  // Rest of the code...
}

export default processDataset;
```

Comment: Are you sure the library is been fetched properly? Can you see it loading in the 'network' tab with the resource requests?

Comment: @MKougiouris Yes, it is loaded, as I said I use d3 directly on the HTML file and everything is fine there